# new relic php agent set custom error reporting level

Tags: php, newrelic, error-reporting

I recently had to add a few old XTC shops to our server which is monitored via NewRelic. But now I keep getting alerts caused by a too high error level.

**Is there a way to make the newrelic php agent ignore E_WARNING, E_NOTICE and E_DEPRECATED?**

It seems like too much work to fix all the errors, but I would still like to have the shops monitored for exceptions/fatal errors if somehow possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New Relic will respect the error_reporting directive within PHP. If you set the error_reporting so that these are not seen as errors New Relic will not capture these as errors.

You can find more info about the error_reporting setting here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Damn. I hoped that would not be the case. For some reasons `ini_set("error_reporting", ...` occurs +30 times in these projects, which makes it extra hard to set the proper error_reporting level ... but thank's for the answer anyway.

Comment: for comment, newrelic does not show in its dashboards error levels E_NOTICE or E_USER_NOTICE.